# Mongo DB aggregate match not returning value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have the following mongo db schema and I am trying to build an aggregate query that searches under `github_open_issues` under the `repo` key and can return me a match for all the values with `repoA` as the value. I have tried the following as my query however its not returning any result. Im a bit confused why this is not working as I have another db with a schema similar to this and this type of query works there but here something seems to be different and is not working. I have also put together this interactive example [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IdPWMU1yPdX)

#### query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$github_open_issues"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "github_open_issues.repo": {
        "$in": [
          "repoA"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  
])
```

#### schema

```
[
  {
    "github_open_issues": {
      "0": {
        "git_url": "https://github.com/",
        "git_assignees": "None",
        "git_open_date": "2019-09-26",
        "git_id": 253113,
        "repo": "repoA",
        "git_user": "userA",
        "state": "open"
      },
      "1": {
        "git_url": "https://github.com/",
        "git_assignees": "None",
        "git_open_date": "2019-11-15",
        "git_id": 294398,
        "repo": "repoB",
        "git_user": "userB",
        "state": "open"
      },
      "2": {
        "git_url": "https://github.com/",
        "git_assignees": "None",
        "git_open_date": "2021-04-12",
        "git_id": 661208,
        "repo": "repoA",
        "state": "open"
      }
    },
    "unique_label_seen": {
      "568": {
        "label_name": "some label",
        "times_seen": 12,
        "535": {
          "label_name": "another label",
          "times_seen": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: the `github_open_issues` field is object, is it actually object in database?

Comment: First thanks for your question, but I dont fully understand it but yes github_open_issues is object and its actually in the database. I have full working example where i have reproduced my issue here https://mongoplayground.net/p/IdPWMU1yPdX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$objectToArray` convert `github_open_issues` object to array in key-value format
- `$filter` to iterate loop of above converted array and filter your search condition
- `$match` to filter `github_open_issues` not empty
- `$arrayToObject` convert `github_open_issues` array to object

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      github_open_issues: {
        $filter: {
          input: { $objectToArray: "$github_open_issues" },
          cond: { $in: ["$$this.v.repo", ["repoA"]] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $match: { github_open_issues: { $ne: [] } } },
  { $addFields: { github_open_issues: { $arrayToObject: "$github_open_issues" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6R_N5OEfWoP)

Comment: Thanks this is defiantly what i wanted to do, however is there another way to do this without the `addFields` ? our running mongo version is 3.2.10 and looks like this is not supported until 3.9 I am also seeing about upgrading our version as its kind of old.

Comment: use $set instead of $addFields, but the other operators $objectToArray and $arrayToObject wont work because its started from mongodb 3.4.4. so there is no other way to do this in mongodb 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

You query is correct but you data in schema placed wrong inside **github_open_issues.repo** your objects are place by numbers like **{"0": {values... }, "1":{values... }}** which cannot get your desired value. You can check the playground now [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hQ5PdtSi6fe)

Comment: this wont work as the number values exist in the schema and cant remove them.

Comment: Then the other answer is for you.